# Ubuntu 13.10 cannot recognizes HDMI

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've a DELL XPS 15 with NVidia Optimus tech, and after Ubuntu upgrade it can't recognize  my HDMI/DisplayPort anymore.

After connect my HDMI it just doesn't appear in my Display application.

I know that Nvidia property driver is not working completely properly with it, but before the upgrade I could use my second monitor just fine.

---

**lspci -v**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
Memory behind bridge: f0000000-f10fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2010
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
Memory at f1c05000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at f1c0a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 54
Memory at f1c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: f1b00000-f1bfffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: f1a00000-f1afffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: f1900000-f19fffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f1800000-00000000f18fffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at f1c09000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]
I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]
I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]
I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
Memory at f1c08000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
Memory at f1c04000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
Memory at f1b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number ac-72-89-ff-ff-ca-25-fb
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
Memory at f1a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
Memory at f1804000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at f1800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

---

**xranr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

---

**xorg.conf generated using command: sudo Xorg :1 -configure**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option        "Protocol" "auto"
    Option        "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option        "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor3"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "SWcursor"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "kmsdev"                 # <str>
    #Option     "ShadowFB"               # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "NoAccel"                # [<bool>]
    #Option     "AccelMethod"            # <str>
    #Option     "Backlight"              # <str>
    #Option     "DRI"                    # <str>
    #Option     "ColorKey"               # <i>
    #Option     "VideoKey"               # <i>
    #Option     "Tiling"                 # [<bool>]
    #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"      # [<bool>]
    #Option     "VSync"                  # [<bool>]
    #Option     "PageFlip"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"        # [<bool>]
    #Option     "TripleBuffer"           # [<bool>]
    #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"        # [<bool>]
    #Option     "HotPlug"                # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"         # [<bool>]
    #Option     "XvMC"                   # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ZaphodHeads"            # <str>
    #Option     "VirtualHeads"           # <i>
    #Option     "TearFree"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"         # [<bool>]
    #Option     "FallbackDebug"          # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"      # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"       # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DebugWait"              # [<bool>]
    #Option     "BufferCache"            # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "ShadowFB"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "Rotate"                 # <str>
    #Option     "fbdev"                  # <str>
    #Option     "debug"                  # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "ShadowFB"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DefaultRefresh"         # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"     # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card3"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen3"
    Device     "Card3"
    Monitor    "Monitor3"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I've spent some days trying to get it working but with no success.

Ps: I've installed bumblebee and bumblebee-nvidia, otherwise my X didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Same here on a Siemens laptop: without NVidia driver, no HDMI.  I circumvented the NVidia driver problem by adding "bleeding edge" drivers (not yet released to the general public)

If that's the route you want to take too, just add the PPA of xorg-edgers (you can roll back to previous drivers if the latest (but not always greatest) doesn't work)